# How strong is skill learnt in one month?

Tags: resume, skills, cover-letter, learning

I have literally spent one month to learn about project/task/time management by read every Wikipedia and Stack Exchange page that sounds relevant. Because I have a chance to use those skills in a megaproject named My Life, I think I have somewhat experience for this. But a one-month skill is a one-month skill, and I wonder how strong it is.

Here's what goes into my cover letter:

> **Project, task and note management**: how to well manage all of them is a real conundrum, since not only they are convoluted together, but also there are myriad methods to approach and apps to test out, each of them address a different level of complexity and combination of the aspects. Really knowing what we want and which tool to achieve is important here. For projects contains tasks span for several days to complete, kanban method is the solution for organizing, visualizing and prioritizing the tasks and flow. In some cases, story point might be a better metric to evaluate and prioritize tasks than hour. If there are not much things to research, burn down, burn up and Gantt charts can be used to extrapolate the delivering day. To manage all the ideas that coming as flood, a note-taking system that has multiple levels of section is very helpful.

Should I put this into my cover letter? Should I list them in my CV, as if I do have much experience on it? How strong is it really?

Besides this skill, I also have been reading a couple books on typography, since this will be a plus on my job. I think the situation is not much far apart.

Comment: I assume English is not your first language? Are you applying for an English-native job?

Comment: no, I'm not a native speaker. I'm not applying for an English-native job, but English is required, and I'm trying to learn English here. I'll fix the language later.

Comment: Ah, the concern I have is that the English is bad enough that the content doesn't really matter. There are also some other problems in terms of how you're pitching yourself. Will try and compose my thoughts into a proper answer later.

Answer (score 7):

One month of reading, especially with minimal real-world practice applying the ideas, does not make you an expert. It barely makes you aware of the general outlines of the issue. This is an interest, not a skill yet.

Answer (score 1):

What are the projects you have done in your life? What was the budget in terms of money and time on those projects? These are the questions you'll have if you want to say that you have project management experience. While you have read about it for one month, are there specific projects in your life you carried out successfully? Have you actually used Kanban? Have you done projects that involved friends? These are points to note as if you spent a month running volunteer projects for a local non-profit where projects coordinated a dozen people with a six figure budget then you may have some experience to discuss but at this point it looks rather hypothetical. Listing what could be used but that you don't have direct experience may well be playing with fire to my mind. After all, if you get asked about planning poker and velocities how well are you prepared to answer those questions and go further down the rabbit hole.